# Interpreting HIDAPI python output

Tags: python, hidapi

I would like to read a string from a USB HID scanner with Python on OS X.  The example below is my starting point and I have been able to tailor the code to my scanner: I have been able to execute the command: h.open() successfully and printout the manufacturer and product strings. The [scan codes were verified with EVDEV with the scanner.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40389059/4953146)

The challenge is interpreting the data returned and mapping it back to an ascii string.

[This post provides python HIDAPI example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41817287/4953146):

```
 from __future__ import print_function

import hid
import time

print("Opening the device")

h = hid.device()
h.open(1118, 2048) # A Microsoft wireless combo keyboard & mouse

print("Manufacturer: %s" % h.get_manufacturer_string())
print("Product: %s" % h.get_product_string())
print("Serial No: %s" % h.get_serial_number_string())

try:
    while True:
        d = h.read(64)
        if d:
            print('read: "{}"'.format(d))
finally:
    print("Closing the device")
    h.close()
```

`$ sudo python try.py`output:

```
Opening the device
Manufacturer: Microsoft
Product: Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
Serial No: None
read: "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"

--8<-- snip lots of repeated lines --8<--

read: "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 22, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 4, 9, 7, 0, 0, 0]"
read: "[0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"
^Closing the device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 17, in <module>
    d = h.read(64)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

## Questions

I was unable to find good examples ([like those found with EVDEV](http://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)).  Any link to the equivalent would be incredibly helpful.  **It is a challenge to interpret the output without good documentation.**  h.read() returns a list

1. Why is 64 selected for h.read()?

   d = h.read(64)

When 64 is replaced with a number from 1,2,3...8, the number of elements in the list is the same.  9 or more results a list of 8 elements.

2. Why is the variable 'd' an output list of 8 elements? (8 is not specified anywhere)

   print('read: "{}"'.format(d))
3. What does each printed output list represent?  1 typed character?
4. What does each column in the output list represent \ encode?
5. Is there a published tabled that maps the numbers to the keyboard?

I am looking forward to responses: **if you have experience using the HIDAPI (especially with Python) please state this in your answer.  Enter the double-bonus round for HID scanner experience**

Answer (score 2):

HIDAPI (which is what Python is using) does not retrieve descriptors, which is what you need to parse the incoming data.
What you need is a way to dump and decode these descriptors:
https://github.com/todbot/mac-hid-dump
https://eleccelerator.com/usbdescreqparser/

Answer (score 1):

You need to read and understand the the USB HID specifications.

[Hid Specs](https://www.usb.org/documents?search=HID&items_per_page=50)

Press the search button and see the documents. This one is most important: "Device Class Definition for HID 1.11"
Also see the "Usage page" documents.

Every device sends a HID-descriptor that exactly describes every single bit in the report. So to interpret the report, your code can either parse the descriptor (api) or you can manually assign the bytes/bits to a struct (not recommended since it only works for well known devices).